# Can you say tehillim on nittel nacht?

Tags: halacha, tehilim-psalms, christianity, evening-night

Since we say tehilim in maariv and kriat shema al hamita, why not tehilim alone on this most unholy night?

Comment: Just in case you are not clear, nittel nacht is not a universal custom. Many Jews do learn Torah...

Comment: According to Kabbalah it's best not to say Tehillim at night in general.

Comment: @shmosel isn't that תורה שבכתב  in general?

Comment: @Shababnik Yes.

Comment: Simply put, the answer is: If you are concerned for the various reasons as to why people don't learn on nittel nacht (which is not necessarily Dec 25) then simply go to sleep. If you're not concerned then continue as usual.

Comment: @Shababnik I've heard that many modern practitioners of nittel nacht use it to tear toilet paper for for Shabbos for the whole of the next year